# How to run SQL script file from SQL Server CE  [Windows mobile]  from c# dynamically?

Tags: c#, sql-server, deployment, windows-mobile, sql-server-ce

I have a Windows mobile  6 application which uses SQL Server CE 3.5 ...
So while installing the CAB into device it will create a database called `TestDB.sdf`.

Now when the application has changed some features and added some column/deleted some column /created new table in SQL Server CE DB,and finally deployed the CAB.

This time the CAB file will uploaded into server,from server all the Mobile device check for new release and install new release on device.

At this time,the application itself taking a backup of its local db [which contains many valuable data]and install new version with fresh DB with all Table change.

After installation,the application itself replacing the fresh DB with the database backed up just before.

At this time we will loose the fresh DB that has database changes.

So, for this to solve,

can I pass a script file [which has all the `ALTER` statements for new/change column and `Create Table` statements for new tables] along with CAB file to device, and execute script file one by one?

How can I do this....?

please help me on this.....

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how the update or installation works but can't you just issue an ADO.NET statement to the database once the sql update file is received?

Comment: thnx for reply....No the  application downloading new version if available in server by using some Logic like by checking some version number in DB.  but, if we download the sql script file to the device i will set Column "isDBChangeExist" to 'True' in Db .By checking this i want to Execute the Script file...but sql server ce doesnot support batch query execution...so how can i do this.....plz

Comment: Look here: http://www.codewiz51.com/blog/post/2010/03/15/Simulating-a-batch-query-with-SQL-Server-CE.aspx to see how to execute a batch script file on SQL Server Ce

Comment: Simply put, its just splitting the file with the GO command and running each statement seperately.

Comment: How to Add Script is embedded as an application resource to Retrieve script from resource...or can i add .sql file as a resource file with the CAB file...and read and execute  this file from c# as normal file reading ??

Comment: Add a text file with the sql commands as content to your solution, just verify the sql syntax. Proceed to read it like a normal file.